# How to convert synchronous code to async Python?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, optimization, async-await

I have been working on a code that would create owners and lots and assign lots to each owner. While I got the code to work, it takes too long to run and was thinking about improving it by making it asynchronous. I have been watching a few videos and reading resources online but I am still confused as to how to implement this. I was wondering if it would be possible for someone to guide me how to accomplish this feat and optimize my code for performance.

Here is the code below:

```
def handle_csv(csv):
    database = pd.read_csv(csv)
    lot= database[['lot_description','lot_number', 'lot_rate']]
    owner = database[['account_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'occupation']]
    address = database[['area','lot_number', 'account_number','street_name', 'street_number']]

    for index in database.index:
        try:
            owner_new = Owner.objects.get(pk=owner["account_number"][index])
        except:
            owner_new = Owner.objects.create(
            account_number=owner["account_number"][index],
            first_name= owner["first_name"][index],
            last_name= owner["last_name"][index],
            )
            owner_new.save()

    
        try:
            lot_new = Lot.objects.get(pk=lot["lot_number"][index])
            
        except: 
            lot_new = Lot.objects.create(
                lot_number=lot["lot_number"][index],
                lot_description= lot["lot_description"][index],
                )
        lot_new.owner.add(owner_new)
        lot_new.save()
```

Comment: What are you using as database engine?
It kind of looks like Django, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Steffo yes it is Django